# Send JSON from Places Autocomplete to Flask

Tags: flask, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm working on my very first web app utilizing the Google Places Autocomplete functionality in the frontend and Flask in the backend.

**Current situation:**

Whenever an address is selected from the autocomplete suggestions, a variable called 'address' is populated in the background containing the API response as JSON. Using a window alert I can confirm that this part works fine.

**To-Do/ issue:**

The address variable should be sent over to Flask so that I can do use it going forward.

Using AJAX to post the data however it never seems to reach Flask. The output is always None.

My best guess is that the submit button implemented after the Autocomplete stuff somehow overrides the JSON POST data in order to keep only the actual text which is in the form while submitting*.

Does that make sense? If yes, how can I still send the JSON data successfully? Or is the issue somewhere else?

I would appreciate any help.

Here is my code:

home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block app_content %}
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}


<div class="container">
    <form class="form form-horizontal" action="" method="post" role="form" novalidate>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&libraries=places&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'),{
                    types: ['geocode']
                });

                // autocomplete.setFields('address_components');

                google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();                                
                    var address = place.address_components;


                    window.alert(JSON.stringify(address));
                    }
                    )})

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/",
                        data: address,
                        success: function(){},
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType : "application/json"
                        });        


        </script>

        <input type="text" id="autocomplete" size=50 style="width: 250px" placeholder="Enter your location" name=inputkiez>
        <a href=# id=autocomplete><button class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button></a>          
    </form>

    <div class="row">
        or check out <a href='/result'> the latest reviews from others </a>
    <div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        jsdata = request.get_json()
        flash('Data is: {}'.format(jsdata))     
        return redirect('/review')      
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/review', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def review():
    reviewform = ReviewForm()
    if reviewform.validate_on_submit():
        userreview = Reviews(               
            reviewcriteria1= reviewform.reviewcriteria1.data,
            reviewcriteria2= reviewform.reviewcriteria2.data,
            reviewcriteria3= reviewform.reviewcriteria3.data,           
            )
        db.session.add(userreview)
        db.session.commit()         
        return redirect('/result')
    return render_template('review.html', form=reviewform)
```

*The text in the form would include the address selected from Autocomplete but without any additional data obviously. I even managed to pass this text to the next page with `request.form.to_dict()` but this is not good enough for my use case since I also want at least the postal code to be sent over.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer to my question but I found a way to send over the data to flask without having to bring in JSON/AJAX at all.

The trick is to send the data from the Autoplaces response as a hidden input of the form:

```
<form method="post" action="">                   
            <input id="userinput" placeholder="Enter a location" type="text" name="name" class="form-control"><br>
            <div id="map" style="height: 300px;width: 300px; float: none; margin: 0 auto;"></div><br>    
            <input type="hidden" name="address" id="address">            
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
            <div>or check out <a href='/result'> the latest reviews from others </a></div>    
        </form>
```

Then in `routes.py` you can easily get the data like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        address = request.form['address']
        # do something
```

This is basically a slightly modified version of the solution posted [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqL0N4fu948) (YT video).